# What type of attack could this be ? (Wireshark pcap)

Tags: wireshark, pcap

[image]

If I understand it correctly the "client" sent an unencrypted password to the pop3 server consisting of a long string of As. Is this a type of attack and if yes, how does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You should ask about attacks and security on [security.se].

Answer (score 1):

The attacker attempts to cause a *buffer overflow*, where the excessively long password is supposed to overflow out of the password buffer into adjacent memory where it's possibly executed as machine code, overwrites essential data, or is used as a stack return address.